# Content in table cell is not showing up

Tags: xcode, uitableview

ich want to make an prototype app and added a table view where i want to put buttons and labels in.
It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I run the app the button for example is not showing up. Does someone know why?
Still if I change the background a a single cell it's not showing.

Comment: I just used the Storyboard editor. Normally everything is showing up i drag & drop in there

Comment: Is this a static or dynamic table view?

Comment: It's a dynamic table view

Comment: In that case, check that your datasource is connected correctly.  If it is, update your question with the code you use to return a row count and a configured cell.